# php regex find too much

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, regex-negation

I want to turn this : `[title->link]`
To this : `<a href='link'>title</a>`

So I have this line of code

```
$content =  preg_replace('/\[(.*)\-\>(.*)\]/', '<a target="_blank" href="$2">$1</a>', $content);
```

On [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/SBCdcF/1), it works well but not in my code.
The issue is that it count the "[" character as a normal character because if the first (.*). So the first group could be very long if there is another "[" before...

bla bla [...] **bla bla [title**->link]
the bold here is my first group but its not what I want...

how to make to stop the first group for the first "[" to maje sute juste "title" is the first group ?

Answer (score 5):

You want to use `[^]]*` instead of `.*`, `[^]]` captures everything that isn't a `]` so it wont pass a `]` while capturing the first or second group, preventing your problem. This wont protect against `[bla bla[title->link]]` including 'bla bla[' in your first capture group, if this sort of nesting may occur, consider adding `[` to the negation group `[^[]]`.

```
\[([^]]*)->([^]]*)\]
```

https://regex101.com/r/SBCdcF/2

EDIT: [Sidyll](https://stackoverflow.com/users/557306/sidyll) pointed out that `-`, `>` and `]` don't require escaping here, but I've elected to keep `]` escaped because it may sometimes have special meaning within a regex.

Comment: Nor the final `]`. It is only a special character if there was a `[` before. In this case, there is none.

Comment: can't hurt though, regex engines are usually pretty nice about too much escaping, and I'd leave a character that may or may not be special always escaped if i don't want it to be special

Comment: True, hurts the eye only. But really, depends on the engine. In Vim default for example the `\[` is the character class. Non escaped is the literal. Characters need to be escaped or not depending on the context. For PHP, the `-` is a special, as long as there is a `[` before. Same with `]`. So that's why I vote for either `\[a\-b\]` or `\[a-b]`. Both are the same :) but let's leave this for the interpretation of the reader. Thanks for your references and nice answer!